# Failed to compile the generated JSP page files

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I have appengine code. It is deploying before and when I try to deploy again it shows following message.

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:826)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:783)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:617)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:385)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

What happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need to make the following two changes in your eclipse configurations.

- Firstly make sure that the Installed JRE in your Eclipse Points to the **JDK and not to the JRE**.
- Secondly add the following argument in **eclipse.ini** and restart your eclipse.

  ```
  -vm
  C:/Program Files/Java/jdkxx.xx.xx/bin/javaw.exe
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the fact that you changed the name of a .java file referenced by one or more .jsp files and the file name did not got changed in the .jsp files.